# WebRtc: SDP to pass video information into video element

Tags: jquery, signalr, webrtc, sdp

I have been working on a Webrtc app for sometimes. I am able to generate an offer and answer SDP and is able to share them. I am using SignalR for signalling. My generated sdp is

```
v=0
o=- 3680533645856578619 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS HmUGEVpPwy5WegeaC2cJ9jGFdJENPeizkOQp
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:ZjR30yYrdGNLe+V7
a=ice-pwd:4LzET7CGUhgGlwWmzkBrDb+F
a=fingerprint:sha-256     AB:33:37:52:4A:4B:17:50:FE:6F:DB:7A:9F:AC:96:EA:AC:AD:17:50:7D:33:79:87:EA:A5:A6:8F:A1:3D:E9:B7
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=maxptime:60
a=ssrc:1542321556 cname:rYLo17fS5RXGhoBe
a=ssrc:1542321556 msid:HmUGEVpPwy5WegeaC2cJ9jGFdJENPeizkOQp dd8dcf3b-8fd7- 4756-9327-d78e89348e8a
a=ssrc:1542321556 mslabel:HmUGEVpPwy5WegeaC2cJ9jGFdJENPeizkOQp
a=ssrc:1542321556 label:dd8dcf3b-8fd7-4756-9327-d78e89348e8a
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:ZjR30yYrdGNLe+V7
a=ice-pwd:4LzET7CGUhgGlwWmzkBrDb+F
a=fingerprint:sha-256     AB:33:37:52:4A:4B:17:50:FE:6F:DB:7A:9F:AC:96:EA:AC:AD:17:50:7D:33:79:87:EA:A5:A6:8F:A1:3D:E9:B7
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000
a=rtpmap:96 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:96 apt=100
a=ssrc-group:FID 1944855956 4157985463
a=ssrc:1944855956 cname:rYLo17fS5RXGhoBe
a=ssrc:1944855956 msid:HmUGEVpPwy5WegeaC2cJ9jGFdJENPeizkOQp d5e52a76-d9c4-47c1-90a4-3da2a9dd2b6b
a=ssrc:1944855956 mslabel:HmUGEVpPwy5WegeaC2cJ9jGFdJENPeizkOQp
a=ssrc:1944855956 label:d5e52a76-d9c4-47c1-90a4-3da2a9dd2b6b
a=ssrc:4157985463 cname:rYLo17fS5RXGhoBe
a=ssrc:4157985463 msid:HmUGEVpPwy5WegeaC2cJ9jGFdJENPeizkOQp d5e52a76-d9c4-47c1-90a4-3da2a9dd2b6b
a=ssrc:4157985463 mslabel:HmUGEVpPwy5WegeaC2cJ9jGFdJENPeizkOQp
a=ssrc:4157985463 label:d5e52a76-d9c4-47c1-90a4-3da2a9dd2b6b
```

i have been successful in passing this information to the remote stream and viz.. but is unable to bind the stream information on the video tag of remote peer.could somebody help

Comment: Most probably your SDP is not complete. What do you mean by "bind the local stream data to remote stream"? That's not the way WebRTC works.

Comment: i guess my SDP  should contains the video information of my source...i want to bind that information to the video tag of the receiver side.. This is all i got when i generated the SDP... @adrian

Comment: Most probably you haven't added the local stream. To bind a stream to a video tag you assign its URL to the source attribute.